# Log4j2 - Missing Delete conditions: unconditional Delete not supported

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using log4j2 in my app and noticed I get the following error:

```
Missing Delete conditions: unconditional Delete not supported
2017-02-16 12:21:25,286 http-nio-8080-exec-7 ERROR Error processing element And ([Delete: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2017-02-16 12:21:25,347 http-nio-8080-exec-7 ERROR Missing Delete conditions: unconditional Delete not supported
2017-02-16 12:21:25,347 http-nio-8080-exec-7 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction for element Delete. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

this is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">C:\\logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}/kiosk.log" filePattern="${basePath}/kiosk -%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy stopCustomActionsOnError="true">
                <!-- custom action executed asynchronously after the rollover -->
                <Delete basePath="${basePath}" maxDepth="2" followLinks="false">
                    <And>
                        <IfFileName path="*/kiosk-*.log." /> <!-- delete only files matching this pattern -->
                        <IfLastModified duration="7d" /> <!-- delete if 7 days or older -->
                    </And>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout   pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="uk.co.kiosk.logging" level="debug" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have also noticed that files were not being deleted after 7days. 
This is my maven entry:

```
dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong, can any one advise? They are creating a the files fine, but not deleting, and then obviously then getting this error in the console.
If there is anything else that I can upload which will help, happy to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<IfFileName path="*/kiosk-*.log." />
```

to

```
<IfFileName glob="*/kiosk-*.log." />
```

The `IfFileName` element doesn’t support `path`, only `glob` and `regex`. See the [user manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover).